# Expression.Invoke не спускается в базу данных

Tags: .net, asp.net, entity-framework

Есть Expression: `{c => Invoke(parameter => (parameter == "054095359"), c.ClientUser.Number)}`

После выполнения запроса в БД уходит запрос без условий в блоке Invoke (делается выборка всех сущностей)
Но если переделать лямбду в следующий вид 
     `{c => c.ClientUser.Number == "054095359")}`, 
то эта фильтрация уже отрабатывается в БД.
В чем тут подвох?

Answer (score 0):

Решение было простым. Оказалось, что c.ClientUser.Number - строка, а тип указанный при создании parameter был object. Т.е. в exrpession нельзя сравнивать object c другими типами